# JAVA | What is an ant build, and why won't the program just run?

Tags: java, class, error-handling, ant, stack

I'm trying to create a stack of random numbers (0-999) that is numElements long. This program displays the largest value in that stack, but after writing the program with no visible errors, it won't run. Upon clicking the run botton, two options come up: one for an ant build with default settings and one that allows for the ant build to be configured. Both result in an error "Unable to find Ant file to run". Why/what is this?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewLinkedStack<T> implements NewStackInterface<T>
{
    protected LLNode<T> top;   // reference to the top of this stack

    public NewLinkedStack()
    {
        top = null;
    }

    public void push(T element)
    // Places element at the top of this stack.
    { 
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);
        newNode.setLink(top);
        top = newNode;
    }     

    public void pop()
    // Throws StackUnderflowException if this stack is empty,
    // otherwise removes top element from this stack.
    {                  
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Pop attempted on an empty stack.");
        else
            top = top.getLink();
    }

    public T top()
    // Throws StackUnderflowException if this stack is empty,
    // otherwise returns top element of this stack.
    {                 
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Top attempted on an empty stack.");
        else
            return top.getInfo();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    // Returns true if this stack is empty, otherwise returns false.
    {              
        return (top == null); 
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    // Returns false - a linked stack is never full
    {              
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void popFromBottom() throws StackUnderflowException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    
    @Override
    public T bottom() throws StackUnderflowException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prompt user for stack size
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many elements do you want in the stack? "); 
        int numElements = s.nextInt();
        s.close();
        // randomly generate numbers 0-999 equal to stack size
        for(int i = 0; i < numElementsInt; i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int number = random.nextInt(999);
            number += 1;
            stack.push(number)
        }
        // print stack
        Symstem.out.print("Top --> " + stack);
        // assertThat(number).isPositive().isLessThan(999);
        // compare top and bot, pop smaller number
        while(stack.size() > 1) {
            Integer top = stack.top();
            Integer bottom = stack.bottom();
            if(top > bottom) {
                stack.popFromBottom();
            } else if (bottom > top) {
                stack.pop();
            } else { stack.pop(); }
        }
        // if stack is size of 1, print 
        Symstem.out.print("Largest number: " + stack.top());
    }
}
```

I was expecting something like this, in which the stack outputs all values and the final largest value, but only get errors and am not able to run anything. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZ4G.png)

Comment: Check your IDE, find  Red color message. (Error Message)

Comment: How do you check your IDE? I'm using Eclipse, not sure if that matters

Comment: I don't see any red error messages. The only error(s) that pop up are when I click run and it says file not found